# php regex global modifier for searching

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have:

```
$pattern = "/a/";
$string = 'Jack is a boy';
preg_match( $pattern, $string, $matches );
```

How do I perform a global search asfter the fitst a. I know in JavaScript one uses the 'g' letter. What about PHP?

Comment: php uses the [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all) function to match with the `g` modifier. And in [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) the global modifier is assumed which is why there is a limit argument.

Comment: What is your expected result?